# Does weight lifting affect finger dexterity?

Tags: piano

I play the piano for around 8 years now but I also work out 3-4 times a week.
Does this affect my finger dexterity since I see people playing for 2 years only and they are more virtuosso than me. Or is this just because I play gospel/jazz and don't practice scales that much?

Most importantly, I want to know how weight-lifting affects my fingers.
Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Without knowing your regimen compared to theirs, it's hard to say anything definitive.  And of course there are innate differences in ability.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Not in my experience.  I don't lift much anymore, but I did when I was younger, and it never got in the way of my playing, either on piano or on guitar.  Make sure you stretch well, especially immediately *after* your workouts, and your muscles should stay limber and flexible.

As for improving your dexterity, the only sure way to do that is through regular, disciplined, daily practice, preferably with a metronome.

Comment: Agreed - I weight train and rock climb, and neither appears to hamper my guitar playing.